# Cordova + Ionic - blend header into iOS header

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using Cordova + Ionic to build a mobile app. I'm wondering if the following is a limitation of using Cordova:

Is it possible to blend the header into the iOS header, or rather change the color of the iOS header to match my header? Like so (Instagram):

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to I guess with the `cordova-plugin-statusbar` found [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar).

Make sure to set correct settings in the `config.xml` file. As described in the GitHub page.

Comment: In addition: If you are using one of the starter templates of ionic the statusbar plugin should already be installed.